# Edit an Excel spreadsheet with Java & JXL API

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I'm currently developing a Java app that's supposed to fill a preformatted Excel file.
The file was originally coded using HTML tags, but I converted it to a real XLS file, removing the conditional formatting in the process (because I saw in [JXL Yahoo! Group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/JExcelApi/) that it makes the thing crash). It then removed the `NullPointerException` I had in the first place, but gave me another, a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` this time.

I have to explain before showing you my code, that the Excel file I'm supposed to fill is contained in the JAR of my application. I extract it in a temporary file to be able to read it properly. This part of my code works perfectly since I use it in others apps without any issues.

Here's my code : http://pastebin.com/WcL9jZZD
And here's the exception :

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
>           at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
>           at jxl.biff.EncodedURLHelper.getFile(EncodedURLHelper.java:60)
>           at jxl.biff.EncodedURLHelper.getEncodedURL(EncodedURLHelper.java:51)
>           at jxl.write.biff.SupbookRecord.initExternal(SupbookRecord.java:203)
>           at jxl.write.biff.SupbookRecord.getData(SupbookRecord.java:254)
>           at jxl.biff.WritableRecordData.getBytes(WritableRecordData.java:71)
>           at jxl.write.biff.File.write(File.java:147)
>           at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.write(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:913)
>           at qctomantis.tasks.ExcelWriter.doInBackground(ExcelWriter.java:128)
>           at qctomantis.tasks.ExcelWriter.doInBackground(ExcelWriter.java:46)
>           at org.jdesktop.swingworker.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>           at org.jdesktop.swingworker.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Does anyone know how to solve this ? I found a [topic](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/JExcelApi/message/12208) in the JXL Yahoo! Group, but they do not give the answer...
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

yes.You are probably using Excel 95 or earlier. Convert the file to Excel 97 or wait for their new release!